# How should I store login FTP credentials inside a python file which is executable by other unix users?

Tags: python, security, unix, credentials

The question is, imagine that I want to create a deploy script which uses 'fabric' deploy library, which has to specify the FTP credentials where you want to deploy to. The idea is that I would like to store this script in our testing server, and from that server, it will deploy remotely to another servers. I would like to create a user account to each developer, but I don't want to share with them the FTP credentials, but rather, give them only the executable, so, if I create a python executable and I added to /user/bin for instance, they will be able to execute it, but also making a 'which mycommand' they can see the source where is inside the credentials, what can I do to avoid it?

Thanks!!

Comment: good question +1 for it.....since its gonna be added to /usr/bin . I wonder if there is something like the .netrc that we could do for all .... or may be depending on the user , it could search for .netrc at the users home dir and work ..... did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you care about security, you probably should be using scp or sftp instead.  These can be set up to not require any keystrokes, while still having decent security.  For more see: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152

However, if you really want/need to use ftp, you probably should put the credentials in a file and chmod it to mode 400: r-------- or perhaps 440: r--r-----.  Embedding credentials in a script isn't a great thing.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, I want the script to be executed, that script has to have inside or from outside credentials for connecting to ftp, and I dont want other unix users to read that credentials, but to execute the script...

Answer (score 0):

- Put the credentials in a file to which the individual developers have no access.
- Create an account that DOES have access to that file but DOES NOT allow interactive logons.  - Create your FTP submission program, make it runnable by this second account.
- Put all the developers in a group (e.g. "Devs").
- Add an entry in the `sudoers` file to allow members of the "Devs" group to run the FTP program without additional authentication.  This will be something like:

  ```
  %Devs    ALL=(ALL) ALL, , NOPASSWD: /path/to/FTPscript
  ```